# Error while using ROS1, OpenCV and GStreamer to read RTSP stream and publishing sensor_msgs::Image

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, ros

I am a newcomer to ROS1, GStreamer and C++. While using cv::VideoCapture vid1.open() to open an rtsp link with cv::CAP_GSTREAMER then publish a sensor_msgs::Image which is converted from the frame read by Opencv, I encountered a quite confusing error:

```
[ WARN:0@1.183] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1697 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query duration of stream
[ WARN:0@1.183] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1728 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=0, duration=-1
[publish_cam_ros_1-1] process has died [pid 4388, exit code -11, ...]
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

If I print OpenCV's build information, GStreamer shows as available:

```
  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
      avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
      avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
      swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
      avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

**Initializing the necessary variables:**

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher pub_1_;
cv::Mat frame1;
cv_bridge::CvImage br;
std_msgs::Header header;
sensor_msgs::Image cam1;
pub_1_ = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("/Cam1/image", 10);
header.frame_id = "base_link";
```

**The code I use to open rpts link:**

```
cv::VideoCapture vid1

string port_1 = "rtsp://<myIP>/channel=0&stream=1.sdp? drop-on-latency=true latency=0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=0 caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR"

vid1.open(port_1, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER)
vid1 >> frame1
```

**Then converting frame1 to sensor_msgs::Image:**

```
header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
br = cv_bridge::CvImage(header, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8, frame1);
br.toImageMsg(cam1);
pub_1_.publish(cam1);
loop_rate.sleep();
```

---

After running the C++ file, I encountered the aforementioned error. However, when I replaced the code for publishing a message (the code below "Then convert frame1 to sensor_msgs::Image") with the code cv::imshow as follows, the program ran totally fine without any errors:

```
cv::imshow("Cam 1",frame1)
if(cv::waitKey(1) == 'r')
   break;
```

---

Could someone please help me identify the error in my program and explain why I'm unable to publish an Image message? Thank you very much in advance.